# Melhor método de descobrir o estado

Tags: javascript, html5, geolocalização

Estou precisando descobrir o estado que o usuário esta acessando a pagina, para o select já vir marcado, e algumas funções habilitadas.

Estava vendo que descobrir o estado a partir do IP é bem falho.
Ai vi que tinha como usar a Geolocation do HTML5, porem ele só retorna a latitude e longitude. Teria alguma forma dele retornar o estado ?

Tava procurando alguma função que retornasse o estado, depois de informar a latitude e longitude, mas não encontrei.

Alguém sabe o que posso fazer, para conseguir com precisão qual estado o usuário esta acessando ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando HTML5 e OppenStreetMaps fica assim:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(posicao) {
    var url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat="+posicao.coords.latitude+"&lon="+posicao.coords.longitude+"&format=json&json_callback=preencherDados";

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});



function preencherDados(dados) {
  alert(dados.address.state);  
}
```

Comment: Qual o grau de acerto ? Ele consegue acertar 100% os estados ? Ou ainda é preferível eu colocar algo para ele confirmar o estado que ele realmente esta ?

Comment: Em navegadores que suportam HTML5 acredito que seja 100%. Nunca tive problemas com esse código, até já usei em um site de aluguel de carros por todo o pais e sempre funcionou. O ideal é que ao preencher a cidade, o estado ou qualquer campo que retorne ai é deixar flexivel a edição.