# Como identificar qual cidade o usuário esta?

Tags: php, javascript, geolocalização

Em alguns sites de compras/serviços é feita uma identificação ou sugestão da cidade que o usuário se encontra para poder mostrar apenas os produtos/serviços específico da cidade do usuário.

Detalhe, isto será utilizado apenas para usuários não cadastrados, por que estarei obrigando o cadastro da cidade e assim poderei fazer o filtro corretamente, mas sem este registro como poderei fazer ?

Comment: Normalmente por GeoIP

Comment: Vale notar que é bom usar apenas como sugestão, pois atualmente não há um método preciso de se determinar isto. (a não ser que se trate de um dispositivo com GPS, e este esteja liberado. e mesmo assim, a informação pode não estar correta).

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106002/melhor-m%C3%A9todo-de-descobrir-o-estado

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tem vários exemplos e códigos prontos na internet, mas basicamente o que você deve fazer é:

1) Obtenha as coordenadas com a Geolocalização do HTML5: [w3schools - HTML5 Geolocation](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)

```
//Check if browser supports W3C Geolocation API
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 
//Get latitude and longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var long = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

2) Obtenha a cidade a partir das coordenadas com a API do google: [Developers Google - Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

```
"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/jsonlatlng='+lat+','+long+'&sensor=true"
```

### Exemplo de código:

[stackoverflow - Get city name using geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6797569/get-city-name-using-geolocation)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<title>Reverse Geocoding</title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var geocoder;

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunction, errorFunction);
} 
//Get the latitude and the longitude;
function successFunction(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    codeLatLng(lat, lng)
}

function errorFunction(){
    alert("Geocoder failed");
}

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      console.log(results)
      if (results[1]) {
        //formatted address
        alert(results[0].formatted_address)
        //find country name
        for (var i=0; i<results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
            for (var b=0; b<results[0].address_components[i].types.length;b++) {

              //there are different types that might hold a city admin_area_lvl_1 usually does in come cases looking for sublocality type will be more appropriate
                if (results[0].address_components[i].types[b] == "administrative_area_level_1") {
                    //this is the object you are looking for
                    city= results[0].address_components[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //city data
        alert(city.short_name + " " + city.long_name)


        } else {
          alert("No results found");
        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script> 
</head> 
<body onload="initialize()"> 

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Antonio, sei que estes links podem ter um conteúdo muito útil,mas prefira transportar para ca na sua resposta o essencial, um exemplo de código uma explanação, por que os links podem quebrar e sua resposta não será mais valida.

Comment: Para postar links, você pode usar o campo de comentários. Para  elaboração de resposta, é importante exemplificar, pois caso os links deixem de funcionar, sua resposta não fica inválida.

Comment: `+1` pegou a cidade corretamente, mas a precisão do setor foi bem fraca, pegou um setor que fica há 25km daqui kkkk, imagina se for uma cidade pequena, será que localiza ?

Comment: Estou numa cidade bem pequena(7k habitantes) e ele detectou uma cidade vizinha (fica a 10km daqui). A precisão do geolocation varia de acordo com o navegador e dispositivo. Em geral, ele é mais preciso que a localização apenas pelo IP, pois ele tem acesso a todos os recursos de localização que o browser disponibilizar.

Comment: Bom, sei bem que ele é bem melhor que o GEO IP, mais sempre é bom deixar o usuário alterar se for preciso... Por exemplo se for pre-preencher um campo com os dados do geolocation seria bom deixar o campo editavel...

Answer (score 12):

Use o GeoIP, ele não dá a localização exata da cidade, mas a região aproximada do seu ponto de acesso através do IP do usuário.

#### Exemplo

```
<?php
$record = geoip_record_by_name('192.168.0.1');
if ($record) {
    print_r($record);
}
?>
```

A variável `$record` retorna valores tais como, continente, país, cidades, longitude, região, código da área, etc.

Para saber os parâmetros retornados, de uma olhada no [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.geoip-record-by-name.php).

#### Obs

Necessita de instalação.

[Instalação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/geoip.setup.php) para Linux / Windows

[Instalação](https://software.opensuse.org/package/php5-geoip) no Linux (OpenSuse)

Comment: Tem algum detalhe em habilitar o mesmo ? estou usando o `php 5.6.9` e no meu php.ini não encontrei nenhuma extensão de geoip para habilitar...

Comment: Editei a resposta com o tutorial de instalação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/geoip.setup.php

Answer (score 8):

Usando Geolocation HTML5 e dados geográficos do OpenStreetMaps:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(posicao) {
    var url = "http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat="+posicao.coords.latitude+"&lon="+posicao.coords.longitude+"&format=json&json_callback=preencherDados";

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
});



function preencherDados(dados) {
  alert(dados.address.city);  
}
```

Comment: Acho que se puser um exemplo de uso do geolocation deixa a resposta mais completa. A parte da localização reversa já está boa.

Comment: Muito legal, este OpenStreetMaps, ele tem algum diferencial por que a precisão dele é identica ao do google maps é claro nos teste que realizei aqui

Comment: Para quem estiver usando JQuery, como eu, remova o último parâmetro da querystring e execute: $.getJSON(url, preencheDados);