# Pegar localidade de acesso com PHP

Tags: php

Estou criando um sistema de acesso ao site para um cliente onde irá conter:

> IPAcesso, DataAcesso (Datetime), Local

Porém gostaria de saber se o PHP tem alguma função nativa que pega a localidade de quem acessou o site. Por ex.: Se um usuário acessar o site do Rio de Janeiro, me retornar **Rio de Janeiro**.

Tentei usar o geoip_record_by_name(), mas parece que no servidor remoto do cliente não tem essa função habilitada.

```
<?php
$local = geoip_record_by_name($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if ($local) {
    print_r($local);
}
?>
```

Comment: Anderson. Já havia acessado esse link que você passou e esse também: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106003/como-identificar-qual-cidade-o-usu%C3%A1rio-esta porém em ambos mencionam a função que passei. Preciso de saber se o PHP tem outra função nativa que não seja a geoip_record_by_name() conforme mencionado nos links.

Comment: Pois se não tiver, terei que usar Javascript mesmo. Mas gostaria que fosse com PHP.

Comment: Tem bem mais respostas que além da resposta marcada como correta, com várias alternativas: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/38448/3635 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/141585/3635 por exemplo. Experimente todas, se ainda não tiver sucesso então irei reabrir a pergunta.